# I would like to bring some cloud docs to AU

Tags: discussion

I would like to break this up into "Ask Ubuntu-able" content:

- https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/05/21/ubuntu-cloud-documentation-14-04lts/

However the scope is rather large and I'll be doing this in chunks, I just wanted to let people know that I would like to make this content more digestable for people so they can consume it.

If you want to help me out:

```
bzr branch lp:~jujudocs/clouddocs/trunk clouddocs
```

Then cd into the clouddocs directory; all the content is Markdown, it just needs to be broken up to answer specific user questions that exist here, or broken out into new CW questions.

Thoughts/opinions before I get started? Don't worry, I won't be posting 45 page monster blocks of text.

Comment: Actually this would be a nice (but contested?) way for junior users to gain some rep. Is there any copyright on the text?

Comment: @don.joey Copyright or not, it shouldn't really be copied or quoted *en masse*.

Comment: I am mostly cutting out most of the intro stuff and the "fluffy" parts.

Comment: @Jorge "Fluffy"!?! How very dare you